# Mavenizing Mule project from gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to move my Mule ESB project from gradle to maven due to test case issues. I understand I need to remove the .gradle file from the project and when I click on mavenize , nothing happens in Anypoint studio. Any suggestions ?

Comment: "Test case issues"? I would advise against moving from a modern and well performing build system to an older, slower one. Possibly you should analyze and solve your testware issue instead.

Comment: Use Gradle or Maven should not influence your tests. Most likely you have something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

To mavenize your project you may use Eclipse because this IDE is best suitable with Maven. You'll need to download [eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), and then add mule support in it. Follow this [tutorial](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/studio-in-eclipse) to do the same. After that import your project in eclipse and mavenize it. You make take help from this [example](https://github.com/ddossot/mule-webapp-example) by David Dossot, to configure a mule project with maven.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AnyPoint Studio, you can create a Mule application and it will already be set up for use with Maven. I would then bring my application artifacts into the newly created project. This way you start with a fresh project that's set up correctly for Maven. Also, you will learn more about things by bring in your mule config, app properties, deploy properties, java classes, and tests into a correctly formatted project structure. You will leave any Gradle artifacts behind. I don't know what button you are clicking called "Mavenize" but Anypoint Studio will allow you to create a shell project that works with Maven. Just create a Mule Application project and copy/paste in the pieces from your existing application. Don't use Eclipse to set up a Maven Mule application project. That's backing up and not utilizing what's available to you.